# msbuild task error while loading Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I've written a custom task for analyzing code coverage results. While building the entire solution, I get the following error.

```
error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find 
the file specified.
```

I checked the path specified during the build process and the dll location is correct. Yet, i get a FileNotFoundException.
Am I missing something?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. I had to add the assembly to the GAC using gacutil.exe. The error vanished once the assembly was added.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a silly suggestion, but have you checked that you're running the `Visual Studio 200X Command Prompt` and not the `Visual Studio 200X x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` ?

Comment: I just confirmed it. I'm running the 200X Command Prompt only.